# Regular Expressions and getting parts of string

Tags: regex

I have many strings like

```
blip createBlip ( float x, float y, float z, [int icon=0, int size=2, int r=255, int g=0, int b=0, int a=255, int ordering=0, float visibleDistance=99999.0, visibleTo = getRootElement()] )

float float float getElementRotation ( element theElement [, string rotOrder = "default" ] )
```

I need get **parts** of this string, like

```
array(
[1] = blip
[2] = createBlip
[3] = x
[4] = y
[5] = z
)
```

and

```
array(
[1] = blip createBlip
[2] = float x
[3] = float y
[4] = float z
[5] = int icon=0
[6] = int size=2
[7] = int r=255
```

...

Is it possible to do this with regex? If yes, how?

Comment: I guess the number of function parameters is dynamic? It is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: >> ***I need... Help me please.*** << Show us what code you have (so far).

Comment: Please specify the input format. It doesn't become clear from the two examples that you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with regex groups and javascript String.match() method, for example (1st string):

```
var string = "blip createBlip ( float x, float y, float z, [int icon=0, int size=2, int r=255, int g=0, int b=0, int a=255, int ordering=0, float visibleDistance=99999.0, visibleTo = getRootElement()] )";

var result = string.match(/((?:(?:\w+)\s?)+?)\(?\[?((?:(?:(?:(?:\s?\w+)+))\,)+)\s?\[((?:(?:(?:\s?=?\.?\(?\)?\w?)+)\,?)+)\]\s?\)/);
```

result will be an array:

```
["blip createBlip ( float x, float y, float z, [int icon=0, int size=2, int r=255, int g=0, int b=0, int a=255, int ordering=0, float visibleDistance=99999.0, visibleTo = getRootElement()] )", "blip", "createBlip", " float x, float y, float z,", "int icon=0, int size=2, int r=255, int g=0, int b=0, int a=255, int ordering=0, float visibleDistance=99999.0, visibleTo = getRootElement()"]
```

now, result[0] contains complete match, but result[1]..result[n] (n - number of capturing groups) contains strings with parameters within () and [] brackets. Now you can split " float x, float y, float z," by "," to get only parameters.

You should try to generalize that pattern, so that it will match second string and other strings you have.  It looks crazy a little bit, but it is only solution that comes to my mind right now...